# Loop command to drop variables with more than 5% missing values

Tags: loops, statistics, stata

I have a Stata dataset of 2,933 patients and 1,136 biomarkers.

I want to know how to create a loop command since the dataset is huge to `drop` variables that contain more than 5% missing values (variables are listed in the columns, and patients' codes are listed in the rows).

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1712673-dropping-missing-variable-based-on-a-condition-for-huge-dataset It is helpful to be told about cross-posting; not telling any forum about cross-posts elsewhere is often deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

```
local cut = ceil(_N * 5/100) 

local todrop 

quietly foreach v of var *  {
    count if missing(`v') 
    if r(N) >= `cut' local todrop `todrop' `v'
} 

if "`todrop'" != "" drop `todrop'
```